# SharePoint Migration 2013

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, migration

What steps do I need to take with Active Directory while SharePoint Migration2013 Process at enterprise level?

1. If it is Content DB method?
2. If it is using any third party tool?

Answer (score 3):

If you staying within same active directory then no need to worry about it.
Whatever method you select either Content DB move or 3rd party migration.

One thing, how you move your User profile service.https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj839719.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396